# Top level files size with powershell

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell

I have the following script it does what I want, but only for one drive (that I have to specify), and on the server I am running it on.

I want to be able to do this for every disk in my server and for every server I have (I have a text file with all the server names).

Here is the code:

```
Param (
    [string]$Path = "F:\",

    [string]$ReportPath = "F:\Monitor_Tasks"
)

Function AddObject {
    Param ( 
        $FileObject
    )
    $Size = [double]($FSO.GetFolder($FileObject.FullName).Size)
    $Script:TotSize += $Size
    If ($Size)
    {   $NiceSize = CalculateSize $Size
    }
    Else
    {   $NiceSize = "0.00 MB"
        $Size = 0
    }
    $Script:Report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Folder Name' = $FileObject.FullName
        'Created on' = $FileObject.CreationTime
        'Last Updated' = $FileObject.LastWriteTime
        Size = $NiceSize
        RawSize = $Size
        Owner = (Get-Acl $FileObject.FullName).Owner
    }
}

Function CalculateSize {
    Param (
        [double]$Size
    )
    If ($Size -gt 1000000000)
    {   $ReturnSize = "{0:N2} GB" -f ($Size / 1GB)
    }
    Else
    {   $ReturnSize = "{0:N2} MB" -f ($Size / 1MB)
    }
    Return $ReturnSize
}

cls
$Report = @()
$TotSize = 0
$FSO = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

#First get the properties of the starting path
$Root = Get-Item -Path $Path 
AddObject $Root

#Now loop through all the subfolders
ForEach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where { $_.PSisContainer }))
{   AddObject $Folder
}

#Create the HTML for our report
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
<Title>
Folder Sizes for "$Path" 
</Title>
"@

$TotSize = CalculateSize $TotSize

$Pre = "<h1>Folder Sizes for ""$Path"" on ""$comp_name""  </h1><h2>Run on $(Get-Date -f 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')</h2>"
$Post = "<h2>Total Space Used In ""$($Path)"":  $TotSize</h2>"

#Create the report and save it to a file
$Report | Sort RawSize -Descending | Select 'Folder Name',Owner,'Created On','Last Updated',Size | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post -Head $Header | Out-File $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html

#Display the report in your default browser
& $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html
```

Comment: To get a list of all local drives consider `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem` and loop through this. For the second part (every server) how do you plan to access them ? Are all servers' drives shared ? Are servers member of a domain ?

Comment: Ok at first i managed to get every disk but there is a problem every disk in my server works fine but the disk that has the script i am running it only shows the folders below the location of my script. does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to do this for every disk in my server

For this, you can use `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem` to retrieve all local drives and loop over the result, something like this :

```
Param (

    [string]$ReportPath = "F:\Monitor_Tasks"
)

Function AddObject {
    Param ( 
        $FileObject
    )
    $Size = [double]($FSO.GetFolder($FileObject.FullName).Size)
    $Script:TotSize += $Size
    If ($Size)
    {   $NiceSize = CalculateSize $Size
    }
    Else
    {   $NiceSize = "0.00 MB"
        $Size = 0
    }
    $Script:Report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Folder Name' = $FileObject.FullName
        'Created on' = $FileObject.CreationTime
        'Last Updated' = $FileObject.LastWriteTime
        Size = $NiceSize
        RawSize = $Size
        Owner = (Get-Acl $FileObject.FullName).Owner
    }
}

Function CalculateSize {
    Param (
        [double]$Size
    )
    If ($Size -gt 1000000000)
    {   $ReturnSize = "{0:N2} GB" -f ($Size / 1GB)
    }
    Else
    {   $ReturnSize = "{0:N2} MB" -f ($Size / 1MB)
    }
    Return $ReturnSize
}

#Get the computer name
$comp_name = $env:computername

#Create the HTML for our report
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
<Title>
Folder Sizes for "$comp_name" 
</Title>
"@

cls
$FSO = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

#Initialize empty result file
Out-File -Force $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html

#Now loop through drives and all the subfolders
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select-object Root
ForEach ($Drive in $Drives) {
  $Report = @()
  $TotSize = 0
  $Path = $Drive.Root
  if(Test-Path $Path) {
     $Root = Get-Item -Path $Path
     AddObject $Root
     ForEach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where { $_.PSisContainer }))
     {   
        AddObject $Folder
     }
     $TotSize = CalculateSize $TotSize
     $Pre = "<h1>Folder Sizes for ""$Path"" on ""$comp_name""  </h1><h2>Run on $(Get-Date -f 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')</h2>"
     $Post = "<h2>Total Space Used In ""$($Path)"":  $TotSize</h2>"
     $Report | Sort RawSize -Descending | Select 'Folder Name',Owner,'Created On','Last Updated',Size | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post -Head $Header | Out-File -Append $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html
  }
}

#Display the report in your default browser
& $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html
```

Also i've managed the fact that you may not have any CDRom in the drive, so, to avoid to throw an exception i use :

```
if(Test-Path $Path)
```

---

> and for every server I have (I have a text file with all the server
>   names)

Well, i cannot answer this point because, as i told you in comments :

- How do you plan to access to these servers ?
- Are all servers' drives shared ?
- Are servers member of a domain ?

---

Finally, you told in comments :

> i managed to get every disk but there is a problem every disk in my
>   server works fine but the disk that has the script i am running it
>   only shows the folders below the location of my script. does anyone
>   know why?

Yes

This will point the current folder :

```
Get-Item -Path "c:"
```

This will point the root drive :

```
Get-Item -Path "c:\"
```

We want the root drive, so you have to use the `Root` property from `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem` to get something like `c:\ d:\`

Have a look at these specific parts of code i've provided :

```
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select-object Root
...
ForEach ($Drive in $Drives) {
  ...
  $Path = $Drive.Root
  ...
  $Root = Get-Item -Path $Path
  ...
}
```

---

Hope it will help.